# cannot get /about vue js vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

When I build production by "npm run build", than access it on a local server (on my machine), than switching page to localhost:5000/about  I get an error:

**Cannot GET /about**

Please help guys. I am on 5th hour and can[t figure this out.. Thanks in advance

webpack.dev.conf.js:

```
'use strict'
const utils = require('./utils')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const config = require('../config')
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const path = require('path')
const baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const FriendlyErrorsPlugin = require('friendly-errors-webpack-plugin')
const portfinder = require('portfinder')

const HOST = process.env.HOST
const PORT = process.env.PORT && Number(process.env.PORT)

const devWebpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  module: {
    rules: utils.styleLoaders({ sourceMap: config.dev.cssSourceMap, usePostCSS: true })
  },
  // cheap-module-eval-source-map is faster for development
  devtool: config.dev.devtool,

  // these devServer options should be customized in /config/index.js
  devServer: {
    clientLogLevel: 'warning',
    historyApiFallback: {
      rewrites: [
        { from: /.*/, to: path.posix.join(config.dev.assetsPublicPath, 'index.html') },
      ],
    },
    hot: true,
    contentBase: false, // since we use CopyWebpackPlugin.
    compress: true,
    host: HOST || config.dev.host,
    port: PORT || config.dev.port,
    open: config.dev.autoOpenBrowser,
    overlay: config.dev.errorOverlay
      ? { warnings: false, errors: true }
      : false,
    publicPath: config.dev.assetsPublicPath,
    proxy: config.dev.proxyTable,
    quiet: true, // necessary for FriendlyErrorsPlugin
    watchOptions: {
      poll: config.dev.poll,
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': require('../config/dev.env')
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(), // HMR shows correct file names in console on update.
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    // https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true
    }),
    // copy custom static assets
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
        to: config.dev.assetsSubDirectory,
        ignore: ['.*']
      }
    ])
  ]
})

module.exports = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  portfinder.basePort = process.env.PORT || config.dev.port
  portfinder.getPort((err, port) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err)
    } else {
      // publish the new Port, necessary for e2e tests
      process.env.PORT = port
      // add port to devServer config
      devWebpackConfig.devServer.port = port

      // Add FriendlyErrorsPlugin
      devWebpackConfig.plugins.push(new FriendlyErrorsPlugin({
        compilationSuccessInfo: {
          messages: [`Your application is running here: http://${devWebpackConfig.devServer.host}:${port}`],
        },
        onErrors: config.dev.notifyOnErrors
        ? utils.createNotifierCallback()
        : undefined
      }))

      resolve(devWebpackConfig)
    }
  })
})
```

My router.js has this code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

const Home = () => import(`./views/Home.vue`)
const About = () => import(`./views/About.vue`)
const Contact = () => import(`./views/contact.vue`)
const NotFound = () => import(`./views/404.vue`)

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: `/`,
      name: `home`,
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: `/about`,
      name: `about`,
      component: About
    },
    {
      path: `/contact`,
      name: `contact`,
      component: Contact
    },
    {
      path: `/404`,
      component: NotFound
    },
    {
      path: `*`,
      redirect: `/404`
    }
  ],
  mode: `history`,
  scrollBehavior: to => {
    if (to.hash) {
      return { selector: to.hash }
    } else {
      return { x: 0, y: 0 }
    }
  }
})
```

But when I am on a localhost "npm run dev" it works well. This issue only happens in production or local server that servs dist folder.

Please help. Thanks..

Comment: Did you checked that import of about that leads to same component dir path ?

Comment: Since you are using history mode, have you set up a proper server configuration?

Comment: Is your server under a sub-directory?